# SQL INSERT INTO table of MS Access. Data not present without reopening db file

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans, sql-insert

**summary** (After running SQL INSERT INTO statement the data is not view-able in the MS Access table without closing and reopening the database)

**What it is:**
Simple Java class using Ucanaccess diver to insert rows into an existing table in MS Access database file.

**To create the condition:**
Open the MS Access database file. Create and save a table with four columns. Name the table "TestExportRows". In addition to the code below, you will need to add to the Java app a user GUI with a button that runs the method. Run the java app, press the button which runs the SQL statement within "public void testExportSingleRow() method". Open table in MS Access database. No records visible. Close and reopen the MS Access database and open the table. Records are now visible. Also, cannot compact and repair database until the Java app is closed.

I've searched long and hard for an answer to this one. I also spent a great deal of time eliminating potential causes. I believe I am closing the connection and statement properly. I need to have this work without the need to reopen the MS Access database or shutting down the Java app.

**Here's the code:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author petehahn
 */
public class Trash {

public void testExportSingleRow() {
 try {

        File dir1 = new File("..");
        String path1;
        path1 = dir1.getCanonicalPath();
        String pathTarget = path1 + "\\" + "Playground.accdb";
        File dbTargetFile = new File(pathTarget);
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" +dbTargetFile +";showschema=true";
        Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        String sqlString = "INSERT INTO TestExportRows(Item,Category,Aluminum,Copper) "
                        +"VALUES ('Column 1','Column 2','Column 3','Column 4')";
        Statement sqlInsertStatement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        sqlInsertStatement.executeUpdate(sqlString);

        dbConnection.commit();
        dbTargetFile = null;
        sqlInsertStatement.close();
        dbConnection.close();

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbTestExportToAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }       
}
```

}

NetBeans 8.0.2 64bit
MS Access 2013 32bit
Windows 8.1 64bit
ucanaccess version 2.0.9.3

Comment: This Access behavior somewhat makes sense since you are using a client to connect to the database but being the same user you are initiating two concurrent user instances. I've had same issues connecting R to Access, even Python with MySQL. Simply, the client must end its session or effectively close its connection prior to opening the backend. If you refresh on the ribbon, do records appear? If you close the Java app and then open db, do records appear? Does same behavior occur with external user?

Comment: Pressing refresh on the ribbon has no affect. Closing the DB and reopening it is the only thing that makes the records visible. The java app can still be open and running. I have not tried connecting as an external user. Not sure how I would do that by I'll look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pete, this is an absolutely known outcome, because 
you're writing on the access file without passing through the microsoft  jet engine.
So Access can't know you're updating the file until it's reopened.
I can't understand what's your real issue or concern.

Ucanaccess can help you to manipulate access files(in all OS), but it can't integrate itself with the Access client.

Notice that a practice with an uncontrolled  concurrent access to Access file from different processes (java through UCanAccess and Access client) is STRONGLY INADVISABLE.

Comment: Wow, so apparently I'm a very long way from my desired solution. I have a client with an existing Java app that connects to an MS SQL server. This Java app performs a highly complex filter on this data and displays results in a jTable. I am just trying to get these results into an Access DB where I am building a user interface to work with these results.

Comment: If you are talking about an Access built-in GUI you may face some problem. If it's a stand-alone app instead, there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Pete, instead of java as the medium, pass data directly from SQL Server to Access (i.e., pass-through query, linked table) unless the filter cannot be expressed in an SQL query. Alternatively, try exporting the jtable to csv, xlsx, txt, or xml which can all be imported into Access (even automated with VBA) without locking the table.